# CodeMirror - Updating selections

Tags: javascript, codemirror

So in CodeMirror you can get a selection by calling [getCursor()](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#getCursor) doing the following:

```
cm.getCursor(true) // start selection
cm.getCursor(false) // end selection
```

This gives you the an object that holds the line and ch position of the cursor. With that you can [mark text](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#api_marker):

```
cm.markText(startPos, endPos, options)
```

Once I have marked the text, is it possible to update it? (without actually deleting it and adding a new mark)

Ex:

```
var t = cm.markText({ line:0, ch:0 }, { line:0, ch:10 });
t.setEnd({ line:0, ch:5 });
```

**EDIT**
Since some people might look for it. This is how you modify marked text:

```
var t = editor.markText({ line:0, ch:0 }, { line:0, ch:10 }, {className: someClass});
t.clear();
t = editor.markText({ line:0, ch:0 }, { line:0, ch:5 }, {className: someClass});
```

Comment: From the documentation: *"The method will return an object that represents the marker (with constructor CodeMirror.TextMarker), which exposes three methods: clear(), to remove the mark, find(), which returns a {from, to} object (both holding document positions), indicating the current position of the marked range, or undefined if the marker is no longer in the document, and finally changed(), which you can call if you've done something that might change the size of the marker (for example changing the content of a replacedWith node), and want to cheaply update the display."*

Comment: @FelixKling I see, thank you. Which makes something like what I'm trying to achieve above pretty complicated.

Comment: I had same problem and come to similar conclusion from looking at the code. What I wanted to achieve is to update marker with different class, when text inside marker changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The way the markers work is actually reversed from what you might think — the lines point to and remember their markers, not vice-versa.

[See the documentation about TextMarker from the source code](https://github.com/codemirror/CodeMirror/blob/master/lib/codemirror.js#L5240).

Here's the relevant quote:

> Line objects hold arrays (`markedSpans`) containing `{from, to, marker}`
>   object pointing to such marker objects, and indicating that such a
>   marker is present on that line.